# Autogeneration of versionCode based on time doesn't always work

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I invoke apk generation via Generate signed apk, sometimes seems like the cache is being overused and the versionCode doesn't change.

Currently my main build.gradle.kts has the following code:

```
android {
    // something

    defaultConfig {
        // something

        versionCode = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60 / 60).toInt() // hour from 1970
        versionName = "${defaultConfig.versionCode} (${Date()})"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    
    // something
}
```

How to make gradle re-generate this information every time with cache enabled?